# error: Cannot access memory at address

Tags: c++

I'm trying to return pointer from function in derived class,
This is the code:

class A

```
class A { 
 protected:
  C c;

 public:
  virtual void func(){
   unsigned char *data;
   int size=getData(data);
  }
}
```

class B

```
class B : public A {

private:
 int size;
public:
 B(const C &_c) { c=_c; };
 const int B::getData(unsigned char *data) const {
    data=(unsigned char *)malloc(size);
    memcpy(data,c.getMem(),size);
    if(!data){
        //err
    }
    return size;
}
```

class C

```
class C {
 private:
  unsigned char *mem;
 public:
  C(unsigned char *_mem) : mem(_mem);
  const unsigned char *getMem() const { return mem; };
}
```

main.cpp

```
C c(...);
B *b=new B(c);
b->func();
```

The error I get when getData returns

```
(this=0x50cdf8, data=0x2 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x2>, size=32)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Youre changing a variable that is function local because the pointer is passed by copy. G.G.

Comment: You need an extra level of indirection. This should be the function signature: `B::getData(unsigned char **data) const`

Comment: I am surprised this code even compiles.

Answer (score 0):

In `class A`, the `func()` is worthless because:
1. `size` is not returned to the caller.
2. The pointer `data` is local to `func` and it's contents will disappear after the end of execution in `func()`.

You don't need to return `const int` from a function.  A function will return a *copy* of variables, so they are constant (copies).

Don't use `malloc` in C++, use `operator new`.  The `malloc` function does not call constructors for objects.

Don't use `new` or `malloc` *unless absolutely necessary*.  Usually, dynamic memory is for containers where their capacity is not known at compile time; or for objects that live beyond a function or statement block's execution time.  If you must use dynamic memory, use a smart pointer (like `boost::shared_ptr`).

Use `std::vector` for dynamic arrays.  It works; it's been tested; you don't have to write your own, including memory management.

You are passing `data` by value (a copy of the pointer).  If you want to modify a pointer, pass it by reference or pass a pointer to the pointer; (what I call the address of the pointer).

Example:

```
void my_function(uint8_t * & p_data)
{
  p_data = new uint8_t[512];
}
```

Or

```
void another_function(unsigned char * * pp_data)
{
  *pp_data = new unsigned char [1024];
}
```

A much better solution:

```
void better_function(std::vector<uint8_t>& data)
{
  data.reserve(64);
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
  {
    data[i] = i;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm working with structs, is it not easier/better to use malloc?

Comment: Don't use `malloc` or `new` unless the class or object is too large for the static or as a static (global) variable.  The problems are: 1) When to delete the memory; 2) Ownership when passed; 3) Copy vs. deep copy.  You can avoid all these hassles by not using `new` or `malloc`.  Allocation on the "stack" is a lot faster (requires incrementing of a pointer, no function calls).  Read up on smart pointers is you really **need** to use dynamic memory.

Comment: Another issue is serializing the objects.  Pointers do not translate well to storage devices; also, when reading in objects, the memory must be allocated (and a new pointer value received).  Again, do you really need all this hassle, when you can declare the variable locally?